# <mat-select> selected value setting but it is not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a parent component like this .

```html
         <form [formGroup]="validateFormGroup">
          <div>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Name" maxlength="150" formControlName="name" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          </form>
          <div class="">
            <app-calendar-time-zones (getSelectedTimeZone)="setTimeZoneSelected($event)" ></app-calendar-time-zones>
          </div>
```

and in the **app-calendar-time-zones** component this is my HTML code  I have

```html
    <div class="calendar-container">
            <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select time zone</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]='selectedTimeZone.displayName' class='form-control'  >

      <mat-option *ngFor="let timezone of filteredTimeZones | timezonesFilter : searchValue" [value]="timezone.id"
                  (click)="timeZoneSelected(timezone)">
        {{timezone.offset + ' ' + timezone.displayName}}
      </mat-option>

    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
      
    </div>
```

And in child component Ts file I am setting the value like this but its mat select element is not setting to the selected value.

```typescript
    this.selectedTimeZone = this.filteredTimeZones[0];

    //  selectedTimeZone  i am getting here is this ==  {id: "Africa/Abidjan", displayName: "Greenwich Mean Time", useDaylightTime: false, rawOffset: 0, offset: ""}
```

Getting the following empty dropdown is displaying. But if i click on dropdown icon i am able to see all the options.
[image]

```
and in the browser if i inspect mat-select element. ngModel value is setting .
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the selection automatic, the value passed via `ngModel` must match the `value` of an Option.

So, I guess `selectedTimeZone.displayName` doesn't match any of the `timezone.id`s bound to your Options.

Comment: That Worked ! Thanks @Francesco Colamonici